# Regarding a conjecture Fogarty proposed

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, hilbert-schemes

In a paper by Fogarty titled "Algebraic Family On An Algebraic Surface,"
he conjectured that $\bf Hilb^n(\mathbb P^N)$ is always variety-- reduced and irreducible.

Is this still a conjecture; any special cases have been treated?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that you mean the Hilbert scheme of length $n$ subschemes of projective space, this is false. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0341. Actually, it is easy to disprove for fixed $N\geq 3$ and large enough $n$: There is a unique component $Z$ that is the closure of the locus of reduced subschemes, and it can easily be checked that the dimension of the locus of subschemes supported at a point is greater than the dimension of $Z.$

Comment: @dhy Thank you so much. Yes. I mean lenght n, 0-dim subschemes. So I see its irreducible, but is it also reduced? even in the case $Hilb^n(S)$ where S is a surface? not necessarily smooth.

Comment: Not precisely the same, but closely related; and see references in answers: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20288/reference-request-is-the-punctual-hilbert-scheme-irreducible

Answer (score 4):

The conjecture is located at the bottom of page 520 in:

Fogarty, John *Algebraic families on an algebraic surface.* 
Amer. J. Math 90 1968 511–521.

In this paper it is shown that $\mathrm{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{P}^N)$ is connected (Proposition 2.3), and  that the $N=1,2$ cases are non-singular rational varieties (Corollary 2.10); although irreducibility was shown by Hartshorne in 1966.

On the other hand, in:

Iarrobino, A. *Reducibility of the families of 0-dimensional schemes on a variety.* Invent. Math. 15 (1972), 72–77.

it is shown for $N\geq 3$ and $n>\!\!>0$ that $\mathrm{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{P}^N)$ is reducible.

So the conjecture is resolved negatively, as stated.

Comment: For online access to Iarrobino's article: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002089513